# How to connect to the database in ASP.NET MVC and Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC site which uses Entity Framework, and I want to publish it as a Web App on Azure.

The problem is that I don't know how to set the connection string to use the available storage on Azure.

I think I should set some values in `Application Settings` in azure portal and publish settings in visual studio, but I don't know how.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Azure Sql database. When the database is created, there's a link in the portal that shows you the connection string. Then, you just have to substitute the connection string for the site to connect to the Azure SQL database.

Comment: Thanks. the app service includes 1GB of storage. isn't it possible to use this without having to pay for database separately?

Comment: No. I don't think that's possible. If you want to use the storage account you'll need to modify your app to use table storage (if it's possible).